# Android apps not communicating

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm actually working on an android wear project and I need a communication between the handheld and the wear module. For this task, I use the DataLayerApi and the MessageApi.

The problem is that the 2 modules (handheld/wear) don't seem to communicate. I've checked the ApplicationId and the package names to see if they were equal, and I don't see a difference.

Does someone know if there's a way to debug it?

PS: I also have a warning from the WearSignatureVerifier saying "No package com.google.android.wearable.app.cn". I don't really understand why I would have a chinese package on my app, so if someone knows more about it, I would be glad to know more about it

Comment: post more information. gradle files

Comment: In the end, I managed to make it. I just needed to declare some listeners (implemented but not added). Thanks for willing to help though

Answer (score 0):

DataLayerApi is working on accessing the wearable data layer.
And MessageApi is working on sending/receiving messages.
So of course, they can't  work together directly.
You should call the data first, translate it into data item then handle it to MessageApi.
Please take a look at [Transferring Assets](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use old google services sdk which is used on your wearables. I mean, 7.8 or similar.